# Converting String into Dictionary via Python containing invalid JSON

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

As above mentions, I'm currently trying to convert a string into a dictionary that looks like below:

```
"{\"SOAPAction\":\"http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger\",\"ID\":\"1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb\", \"info\": {\"GMT\":\"16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000\", \"client\":\"10.177.147.71:42987\", \"frontend\":\"path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804\", \"request\":\"POST /path/service HTTP/1.1\", \"body\":\"\\/path\\/of\\/downloaded\\/file.xml\", \"response\":\"-\"}}"
```

The issue is that the above code currently doesn't convert into a dictionary due to some invalid JSON formatted content. Because of this, I haven't been able to use eval, json_loads etc.

Is there any way to reformat the code so that...

A) It is in valid JSON format
B) It is able to convert the above string into a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have double-encoded Json(?):

```py
import json

s = r"{\"SOAPAction\":\"http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger\",\"ID\":\"1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb\", \"info\": {\"GMT\":\"16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000\", \"client\":\"10.177.147.71:42987\", \"frontend\":\"path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804\", \"request\":\"POST /path/service HTTP/1.1\", \"body\":\"\\/path\\/of\\/downloaded\\/file.xml\", \"response\":\"-\"}}"

data = json.loads('"' + s + '"')
data = json.loads(data)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "SOAPAction": "http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger",
    "ID": "1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb",
    "info": {
        "GMT": "16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000",
        "client": "10.177.147.71:42987",
        "frontend": "path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804",
        "request": "POST /path/service HTTP/1.1",
        "body": "/path/of/downloaded/file.xml",
        "response": "-",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, with `.replace('\\"', '"')`

Code:

```
import json

input_string = "{\"SOAPAction\":\"http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger\",\"ID\":\"1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb\", \"info\": {\"GMT\":\"16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000\", \"client\":\"10.177.147.71:42987\", \"frontend\":\"path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804\", \"request\":\"POST /path/service HTTP/1.1\", \"body\":\"\\/path\\/of\\/downloaded\\/file.xml\", \"response\":\"-\"}}"

#new_string = input_string.replace('\\"', '"')

result_dict = json.loads(input_string)
print(result_dict)
print(json.dumps(result_dict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{'SOAPAction': 'http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger', 'ID': '1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb', 'info': {'GMT': '16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000', 'client': '10.177.147.71:42987', 'frontend': 'path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804', 'request': 'POST /path/service HTTP/1.1', 'body': '/path/of/downloaded/file.xml', 'response': '-'}}
{
    "SOAPAction": "http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger",
    "ID": "1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb",
    "info": {
        "GMT": "16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000",
        "client": "10.177.147.71:42987",
        "frontend": "path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804",
        "request": "POST /path/service HTTP/1.1",
        "body": "/path/of/downloaded/file.xml",
        "response": "-"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this returns with...

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Does this mean it's not in a complete dictionary format so it can't run properly?

Comment: @blackfyr3 please put your input that has a problem, because your input above does not have any problem, without any change (updated code above), it can easily converted with json_loads and view the dictionary in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from json import loads, dumps
from ast import literal_eval

strdict = "{\"SOAPAction\":\"http://www.my-website..uk/path/To/service/v1/serviceAndLedger\",\"ID\":\"1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb\", \"info\": {\"GMT\":\"16/Nov/2022:12:13:46 +0000\", \"client\":\"10.177.147.71:42987\", \"frontend\":\"path/to_my_ip/12.189.66.213:8804\", \"request\":\"POST /path/service HTTP/1.1\", \"body\":\"\\/path\\/of\\/downloaded\\/file.xml\", \"response\":\"-\"}}"

fixdict = loads(literal_eval(dumps(strdict)))

print (fixdict['ID'])
```

Results:

1sceas2-61ae-379dd-a9cd-c813fb07u8inb

```
print (fixdict['info']['body'])
```

/path/of/downloaded/file.xml